# How can I switch between the HDMI and DVI outputs of my graphics card?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, graphics, dvi

I've got an Nvidia GTX 560ti card which currently I've got my 2 monitors hooked up to using the 2 DVI ports.

However its got a mini-HDMI port which I've plugged a HDMI cable in (with mini adapter) and lead it into my TV which is across the room.

I'm hoping to be able to toggle between the HDMI output and the DVI outputs, however I'm not sure how I'd go about this,

Could somebody please point me in the right direction, I'm not really worried about having all 3 on at the same time so that isn't a problem, but if its possible then I'll do that.

Comment: This is ussually done via your graphics card software installed on your computer that ussually is running on the task bar. Do you have this installed?

Comment: Ive only got the nvidia control panel but cant seem to find anything good in there

Comment: I would go to Nvidia's website and see if they have any update or download available to help out with the multiple displays

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem, after re-wiring my house so I could use my TVas a monitor for my desktop (controlled wirelessly by my iPad using the app called "screens") I was unable to figure it out until I started messing with NVidia control panel.

so to do it you need to:

1. go start > control panel
2. select NVidia control panel
3. expand display
4. click on set up multiple displays
   (next two steps need to be done in order)
5. then turn off the one you want to swap out (I used my second monitor for ease)
6. then turn on the one you want to swap in
7. click apply

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, you will not be able to power all three displays independently at the same time on a single nVidia graphics card. You say it's not a problem, but I was just wanting to clarify that point for you in case it came up in the future.

The proper way to switch back and forth using windows 7 would be like such:

1. Open `Screen Resolution` (Right click on desktop -> Screen resolution)
2. Select the display you wish to stop using
3. Change the "Multiple Displays" property to "Disconnect this display"
4. Apply
5. Select the display you wish to start using
6. Change the "Multiple Displays" property to "Duplicate" or "Extend", based on what you wish to do.
7. Apply

Comment: Ah This is getting me half way there! thanks, However when I click Apply it says "Unable to save display Settings"

Comment: @OwenMelbourne #4 Apply, or #7 Apply?

Comment: #7 Apply, I think its because I tried Duplicating the extended display to show on the hdmi and dvi. My new quest is to figure out if there is a way I can toggle the primary monitor between DVI 1 and HDMI hmm

Comment: @OwenMelbourne Ah, My system will only let me have my displays in extended or duplicated mode, never both at the same time. You should be able to switch the primary by checking "Make this my main display" on the new monitor you want to be the primary.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a DVI Splitter or HDMI Splitter it only gives you the capability to display the same image on multiple monitors. If you are looking for extended desktop application you need to buy a video card with multiple outputs.